# What's the best way to store milliseconds in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 9, but the system should work also for Oracle 8 and 10.

The problem is: date fields cannot store anything beyond seconds, but I'm storing a series of events that occur with millisecond precision. The obvious solution is creating a new column to store the milliseconds. But is this the better solution?

It does not seem very clever to me, because doing that imposes that all my queries (there are a plenty of them) will need a change in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I believe Oracle 8 is ten years old, time to move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the timestamp type.  Here is a good explanation of it:

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/database-solutions/a-comparison-of-oracles-date-and-timestamp-datatypes-6681

Although it is not supported in Oracle 8 very well.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 8 you had to do a work around (varchar field or two fields, a datetime and 2nd to hold the milliseconds)

If you can somehow avoid the requirement to do this in Oracle 8, consider the TIMESTAMP datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you choose between supporting Oracle 8 (which is soon to go out of service, if it is not already out of service) and millisecond support.  Of the two, I'd recommend ditching Oracle 8 and only supporting Oracle 9 or later.

[Fair disclosure: I work for a competitor - I'd even recommend switching to us.  If my info on Oracle 8 going out of support is wrong, sorry.  But the advice is as unbiassed as I can make it.]

Comment: Oracle 8 (and 8i and 9iR1) have been out of support for YEARS. Oracle 9iR2 has recently entered the 'lifetime support' category, which basically means no new bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought so - but was too lazy to go searching for the information (and besides, I'm encouraged not to poke at the Oracle site).  So the advice to ignore Oracle 8 is sensible; hence, use TIMESTAMP.  No doubt, they have systems on 8 (or why mention it).  But they're living on borrowed time.

Answer (score 0):

As already mention, timestamp is the datatype in oracle 9 and later that supports the millisecond precision you are looking for.  If you want to support oracle 8 as well then you will have to use a varchar2(25)  to store the value.  In oracle8 you will have to use a java function or external program to get the millisecond precision to store in the table's varchar2 column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to come across this thread. But for earlier versions of Oracle in which Timestamp is not supported. One can always store the value of the Timestamp in a Long datatype column. While storing into the DB, one can save the timestamp.getTime() in java, which returns long. And while reading from the DB, one can read the long value and create a Timestamp by providing it in the Timestamp constructor. Hope this helps someone working on legacy systems.